# sass --watch : Compile only 1 css with many sources

Tags: css, compilation, sass, compass-sass, watch

Hie everyone !

My Sass project looks like this :

```
Project
├── sass/
│   ├── bootstrap/
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── _bootstrap.scss
│   ├── mymodule/
│   │   ├── submodules/
│   │   ├── _mymodule.scss /*with only @import from submodules/ */
|   └── main.scss /* various styles & @import bootstrap, mymodule */
└── stylesheets/
    └── main.css
```

I'm trying to watch every modifications:

- in the whole mymodule folder
- in main.scss

And alterate **only stylesheets/main.css** with modifications i made.

Every commands I wrote have generate mymodule.css or others scss files/folders.

What is the ***sass --watch*** for doing this please ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Alexis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should totally use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)!

### What Compass is

Compass is a must-have tool for every SASS coder. Compass consists of two parts:

- a meta-framework for SASS;
- a command line tool used for compiling Compass projects and doing other useful stuff.

The `compass watch` command is exactly what you're looking for. It will recompile the CSS whenever you save a change in any of the following:

- every non-partial file inside the `sass` folder (in your case it's only `main.scss`);
- every partial imported by one of the above (recursively).

Partials that are never imported are ignored.

Compass will create a separate CSS file for every non-partial file. As for partials, they do not appear as separate CSS files because are incorporated inside non-partials.

### Ridiculously short installation guide

For the following to work, you must have Ruby and [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/pages/download). Probably you already have them.

To start using Compass, do:

1. Install Compass with RubyGems: `gem install compass`.
2. Create a `compass.rb` file in the root of your project (in your case it's `Project/compass.rb`).
3. Run `compass watch` and start coding.

### Example of a config.rb file

Here's a minimal `compass.rb` that might work for you:

```
css_dir =   "stylesheets"
sass_dir =  "sass"
```

Comment: 10000 Thanks lolmaus ! It make absolutely what i wanted. ! It generate a css folder for mymodule but i will delete it, my main.css have everything i want inside. Muchas gracias !

Comment: Just adjust your config.rb according to your preferences. Compass can save the resulting CSS to wherever you want.